# what is source keystore password and how to find it?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, sap-commerce-cloud

I am exploring single sign-on. I have created a account on SSOCircle and exported the certificate for my mozila firefox browser. Now I have to import that into my saml key Store. For that I am using following command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin>keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore  F:\OrbeonB2C_H_6.3\ssocircle.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore samlKeystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Now I am getting following error:

> Enter destination keystore password:
>   Re-enter new password:
>   Enter source keystore password:
>   keytool error: java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45

How to find the Source keystore password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already set source password while creating pfx file. Did you check below document?
https://help.hybris.com/6.4.0/hcd/03eea6e589054c70a0fb25767cb664a1.html

Comment: thanks for your reply @mkysoft. I am refering the same document.